# Unable to add background image in reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have a div as follows:

```
[:div (tw [:flex :flex-col :items-center]
             {:style {:background-color "#ffffff"
                      :background-image "url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='199' viewBox='0 0 100 199'%3E%3Cg fill='%232f855a' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 199V0h1v1.99L100 199h-1.12L1 4.22V199H0zM100 2h-.12l-1-2H100v2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E)"}})
    [:div (tw [:text-5xl :font-bold "mt-20"])
     
    ]

    [:div (tw [:flex :flex-row :items-center])
     [:div (tw ["w-2/3"])
      [:img (tw [ :h-auto] {:src "img/mock.png"})]
      ]
     
     
    ]
```

And I have a background-image key in the style map of the container div. The url is generated from https://www.heropatterns.com. But the background doesn't show. Why would that be?

I'm able to change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

The `:background-image` attribute should look like this

`:background-image "url(\"data:image/svg... \")"`